# How to make Boolean ignore Mask?

Tags: modifiers

What it looks like without Mask:[image]

What it looks like with Mask:[image]

What it's supposed to look like (the reason I don't just use this is because I had to actually create a separate object and hide the Boolean target, and that's destructive workflow):[image]

Basically, I want the Boolean in the pink one to ignore the fact that the blue one has a mask and apply the Boolean as if it's all there.

edit* found a bit of a workaround by applying the Transparent BDSF texture to all faces I wanted invisible.